# Why is my HashMap allowing duplicate keys?

Tags: java, hashmap

Hey I'm using a `HashMap` to keep track of services and service-requests on a BulletinBoard. However, I must have the hashcode and equals wrong because I'm getting duplicate keys. Can anyone tell why this might be?

The content of the keySet:

```
Services: [1, 1, 6, 6, 3]
Requests: [8, 7, 6, 5, 8, 4, 5, 6, 2]
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
private static final HashMap<Advert, Integer> services = new HashMap<>();
...

public class Advert {

private int id;
private BoardPoster poster;

public Advert(BoardPoster poster) {
    this.poster = poster;
}

public BoardPoster getPoster() {
    return poster;
}

public void spawn() {
    id = RANDOM.nextInt(ADVERT_RANGE);
}

public int getID() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return Integer.toString(id);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o != null && o instanceof Advert) {
        return ((Advert) o).id == id;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 67 * 5 + this.id;
}
}
```

Comment: One remark: checking `o != null && o instanceof Advert` is redundant. `o instanceof Advert` returns `false` if `o` is `null`. In Java, `null` isn't considered to be a type of anything, so all instance checks on it fail.

Comment: Since `id` is an `int`, you could simplify your hashcode: `return this.id;`.

Comment: @assylias That's a bad way to do a hashcode, since it's not actually hashing.  returning `this.id % 1000` might be a better option.

Comment: @ErickRobertson It will be used as a key to a map: why would you restrict the possible number of values to 1,000 and therefore **significantly** increase the chance of hash collisions? Generally speaking, you want your hashcode to produce different values for different objects, and in any case use the whole range of integer values.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The likeliest reason is that the objects you use as keys are mutable. So if you do something like:

```
map.put(anAdvert, 1);
anAdvert.spawn(); //modifies id, which affects hashcode and equals
```

The behaviour of the map will be unexpected.

cf [Map's javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

> Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map.

Comment: It's good practice to use the `final` keyword for properties like this.

Comment: Never use mutable objects as map keys!